# ComputeFilesToPublish: copy just the content of a folder to a different folder after the build process

Tags: visual-studio, iis, webdeploy, asp-net-core-spa-services

I am trying to setup a build for an angular 1.6 project, and the build and deployment works, however during the copy I would like to have files copied to a root folder like so:

This is what the source looks like

- _release <- this is where the build happens
- app
- Content

and I would like the content of _release copied to another folder called let's say newbuild. Right now during the copy I get the _release folder as well, not just the content.

How can I go about updating my project file to only copy the content, so everything that is inside the _release should go to newbuild.

Here is what my .csproj currently looks like:

````
    <Content Remove="app\**" />
    <None Remove="app\**" />
    <None Include="app\**" />
    <Content Include="_release\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="AngularBuild" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="r.js.cmd -o app/release.js" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishDistFiles" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="_release\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')*" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>```
````

Comment: I suggest you could try to replace your publishdistfiles to below codes:  `<Target  Name="PublishDistFiles"  AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CopyItems Include="_release\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy
    SourceFiles="@(_CopyItems)"
    DestinationFolder="PreserveNewest"
    />`